# Image click in webview in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am creating a mac application using cocoa framework.
I have added a Webview, in which I have loaded some HTML content.
The WebView is editable.
I have added an image by appending the tag  with HTML content.
Now, What I need to do is to detect the image click? When user click on any image within the webview, I have to display a alert saying "image name clicked".

So can anyone please let me know how to detect image click along with tag information in webview.

Thanks,
iPhoneDv

Comment: Wait iPhoneDv, this isn't for iOS right... (Sorry your name is just misleading)

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is not for iOS,it's for mac application.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very hard once you understand how the webview works, You implement a UIWebViewDelegate. One of the functions there is

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Here you get the url inside request.URL, there you can f.ex. parse it, split by a slash (/) and many more options and check for some parameter you have in the link and then trigger some method inside your code. But you need to return NO so the method does not render the link page.

For this example, I just imagine that all image links are not http://example.com/1.gif but instead picture://example.com/1.gif

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSURL *action = request.URL;
    if ([[action scheme] isEqualToString:@"picture"]) {
        // split url with /
        NSArray *array = [stringUrl componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
        NSLog(@"You just clicked on image : %@", [array lastObject]);
        return NO;
    }
 return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I do the same thing for mac application. It is for iOS apps.

Comment: Your username threw me off. No wonder you are asking, I could not find much information on this